# Wordpress unable to execute function do_shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have very simple custom template.  When I try execute do_shortcode from within my php program I get fatal error:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[shortcodename]'); ?>

    ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function php do_shortcode() in /var/www/wp/wp-content/themes/musustatymai/category.php on line 17
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  233208  {main}( )   ../index.php:0
2   0.0001  233640  require( '/var/www/wp/wp-blog-header.php' ) ../index.php:17
3   0.0376  2924360 require_once( '/var/www/wp/wp-includes/template-loader.php' )   ../wp-blog-header.php:16
4   0.0387  2938176 include( '/var/www/wp/wp-content/themes/musustatymai/category.php' )    ../template-loader.php:75
```

What can be wrong with my template, as I know that is not needed to load wordpress classes manually to get access to methods. Also I tried using  includes.

`wp-includes/shortcodes.php` but get same error.

Comment: may be you are using the `code` outside of wordpress ??

Comment: @PrabinParajuli in category.php

Comment: oh, can you try using `echo apply_filters( 'the_content','[shortcodename]');`

Comment: @PrabinParajuli not working

Comment: prob needs to be hooked after `init`

Comment: Can you show more of what you are doing?  What's the header area on this php file look like?  Where do you definte [shortcodename]?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you have write/load [shortcodename] also in your post, because only writing it in the template alone won't work.

jThis just searches for the shortcode in the post when the loop starts, in order to put the shortcodename elsewhere.

This may explain more:
https://ardamis.com/2011/06/02/fix-for-php-fatal-error-get_header-in-wordpress/